# change pointer inside a function

Tags: c, pointers, pass-by-reference, message-queue

I am making a message queue API in C, but I am having a problem with the receive method. I send a char* message ("BOB") to the message queue and it is successfully stored. I then try to receive the message but that fails.

Inside mq_receive() the correct message is dequeued and ret_val->buf points to 0x012f5754 ("BOB"). Next, msg_ptr (which is originally 0x00000000) is assigned 0x012f5754. Everything works as expected until the program returns to main(). In main(), receive_message is still NULL. I was expecting it to point to the first character of BOB which is 0x012f5754. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

```
//main.c
main(){
    char* receive_message = NULL;
    //message queue init ...
    mq_send(msq_id, "BOB"); //this works correctly
    mq_receive(msq_id, receive_message);      
    printf("return value: %p\n", receive_message); 
}

//message_queue.c
mqd_t mq_receive(mqd_t mqdes, char *msg_ptr)
{
    queue_t* ret_val;
    q_attr* attr_ptr = (q_attr*)mqdes;
    ret_val = dequeue(attr_ptr);
    //all this works ret_val->buf points to BOB
    msg_ptr = ret_val->buf;
    return mqdes;
}
```

Comment: you have to use pointer to pointer instead of just pointer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arguments are passed by value in C, you need to pass the address of `receive_message` to `mq_receive()`:

```
mqd_t mq_receive(mqd_t mqdes, char **msg_ptr)
{
    queue_t* ret_val;
    q_attr* attr_ptr = (q_attr*)mqdes;
    ret_val = dequeue(attr_ptr);
    //all this works ret_val->buf points to BOB
    *msg_ptr = ret_val->buf;
    return mqdes;
}
```

and invoke it:

```
mq_receive(msq_id, &receive_message);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that fixed the problem. Is where some way to accomplish what I want to do with out changing the signature of mq_receive()?

Comment: @mashrur, not that I know of.

Answer (score 0):

To answer you question posted in response to hmjd. There is sort of a way to do what you want without altering the signature.

If you change this:

```
char* receive_message = NULL;
```

To something like:

```
char receive_message[1000];
```

You could then store a *copy* of the received message with `strcpy` without changing the function prototype. But as hmjd said, there is really no way to modify the pointer itself without passing in the double pointer.